# EclipseLink delete and update - migration from Hibernate

Tags: java, primefaces, sql-update, eclipselink, sql-delete

everyone.

I had to recently change from Hibernate to EclipseLink because of the host I'm using right now (GlassFish 4, JEE 7 and JPA 2.1), but I'm having some problems when deleting and updating records in the PrimeFaces datatable.

The column with a delete link in the datatable:

```
<p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Deleta</f:facet>
                <h:form>
                    <h:commandLink action="#{grupoMB.deletaPorNome(grupo.nome)}">excluir</h:commandLink>
                </h:form>
            </p:column>
```

Method deletaPorNome(String nome) -- deletaPorNome = "removeByName":

```
public void deletaPorNome(String nome) {
    this.grupoRepositorio.excluiPorNome(nome);
    this.grupos = null;
}
```

GrupoRepositorio is my Stateless Session Bean with the CRUD operations:

```
public void excluiPorNome(String nome) {
    this.manager.getTransaction().begin();
    Query q = this.manager
            .createQuery("SELECT x FROM Grupo x WHERE x.nome = :nome");
    q.setParameter("nome", nome);
    Grupo grupo = (Grupo) q.getSingleResult();
    this.manager.remove(grupo);
    this.manager.getTransaction().commit();
    this.manager.close();
}
```

No matter what I use in this method: TypedQuery, native query, DatabaseSession deleteObject, etc. Nothing is working. What's the problem?

Comment: Can you describe more of what you mean, for instance, does the object still exist in different EntityManager context?  Try turning on logging and see what it is doing in your excluiPorNome method http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it adding id to the table, then creating method removeById(Long id) in my SLSB:

```
    public void removeById(Long id) {
        Grupo grupo = this.manager.find(Grupo.class, id);
        this.manager.remove(grupo);
    }
```

Then call it in my managed bean:

```
    public void delete(Long id) {
        this.grupoRepositorio.removeById(id);
        this.grupos = null;
    }
```